# moving aspx eval to code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my aspx file, I have some code that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var MyVar = '<% =MyFunction() %>';
</script>
```

All this works fine: MyVar actually holds a json string that later gets evaluated on the client. The problem is that this code was designed for a one-time situation and it's turning out to becoming more than a one-time situation and it just looks messy.

I'd like to move this to my code behind. How could I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Whatz the mess,can you elaborate a bit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your OnLoad:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myVar", string.Format("var myVar = {0};", MyFunction()), true);
```

Comment: +1 Totally agreed, this is a great way to use ASP.NET features to register client-side script from the server without messy control hacks. (Don't forget to put single quotes in your sample like '{0}' to hold a JavaScript string and conform to question);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HiddenField`

```
hfId.Value = MyFunction();
```

when you want to use it in your client side:

```
var MyVar = document.getElementById('hfId').value;
```

Hope this helps
^^